# Some weirdness in my my D3 Stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

One of my stacked bars is behaving in a strange manner, it looks like it is stacking but it is repeating some of the stacks on one of the dates. I'm not entirely sure why? I think it's something going on in my reduce.

Here is that snip of code.

```
   var dataset = [];
data.reduce(function(res, obj) {
  var key = obj.Date;
  if (res[key]) {
  for(i=0; i < uniq_enames.length; i++){
     var name = uniq_enames[i]
     res[key][name] += obj[name];
   }
  } else {
    dataset.push(obj);
    res[key] = obj;
  }
  return res;

}, {});
```

here is the full fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/jamiebrs/6guh43yn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeez, simple answer.

I was missing a data=dataset before I did my stack.